# compacting revisions in an SVN Dump file

Tags: backup, svn, filtering

I have taken a dump of my SVN repository, to migrate to another server, and have noticed that one sub-folder in particular which has 15 revisions changing its content is being pulled across as the full number of revisions for the repository.

Is there a way to compact the number of revisions in the dump file?

The folder has revisions from `509 > 603`, but only has 18 revisions in that range that change its content. I want to remove the other 85 revisions in the range.

I have used `svndumpfilter` with `--drop-empty-revs` and `--renumber-revs`, but it only renumbers them to the same revision. My question/problem, is simply how do i compact the revisions in the dump file to only the ones relevant to that folder? I am getting my information as to the "18 relevant revisions" from an svn log of the folder.

Hopefully I have provided enough information to be clear what I am trying to do and need help with, please let me know if not and I shall update/edit. Thanks

**EDIT**

[image: SVN Log view]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (if you know the revisions with "real changes") is:

1. dump everything from 0:509
2. dump the 18 revisions with `--incremental` switch
3. dumo everything from 603 to HEAD with `--incremental` switch

transfer everything to new server and load them in same order into new repository

Comment: I only wanted to pull those 18 revisions across anyway at the moment, trying to do some changes to repo layout at the same time while merging illicit repositories (facepalm). Where does the --incremental switch go? on the `svnrdump`/`svnadmin dump` command?

Comment: oh yes, `--incremental` on svnrdump, i shall give it a whirl!! i expected the `--drop-empty-revs` to whip out what i wanted but it must look for different criteria (of which im not sure on..)

Comment: are the revision really empty? What is the commit message? who did them? normally SVN does not store 0-changes in revisions(however you can trick the client to send such stuff to the server).

Comment: the log dialog in tortoise just shows 18 revisions, no revisions in there, but the svndumpfilter carries all the revisions through, not sure why.. it has me confused thats for sure!

Comment: incremental switch doesnt seem to do it, just to prove I'm not being crazy I have added a screenshot of tortoise log to the question

Comment: so what does a `svn log -v --limit 1 -r 540 [REPO_URL]` print out? You can alternative look into the pure revision file in the db folder you cannot read the details but still find out what changes are supposed to be written..

Comment: it just prints out a single line of dashes for 540 nothing else. i think ill just have to pull across these mystical revisions, dont really know why it is creating them but i think its possibly taking too much time.. just curious why it is not getting rid of the clearly empty revs!

Comment: the empty revs, the `--drop-empty-revs` is related to is always about the path it tries to match. So (I assume) it does not check for empty revs, but if a certain path is filtered and if there is nothing else inside the revision. clearly first criteria (filtering an existing path) is not true, so it ommits the filter.

Comment: even using include with a pattern or the folder name itself, all those revisions come through!! ARGH `svndumpfilter include --pattern "web*" --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs < web.dump > webfilter.dump` is the command I am running now, and still pulls the revisions through. I think i will just have to use svnrdump -r<rev>:HEAD method in order to cut out all the other revisions I dont need.. thats the only way I can see this "working".